# How to Create a Plugin with the method afterGetData on the class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context in magento2?

Tags: magento2, plugin, magento2.4.3

How can I build this module for our Magento 2 for cache warmer to crawl both desktop and mobile version pages?

We would like to create a plugin with the method afterGetData. On the class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context

In this method of the plugin, I would like to add a condition by which an additional parameter "device-type" is added to that data.

The afterGetData method may look like this one:

```
public function afterGetData($subject, $data)
{
    if ([mobile-user-agent-condition]) {
        $data['device-type'] = 'mobile';
    } else {
        $data['device-type'] = 'desktop';
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Where [mobile-user-agent-condition] is the condition that should return 'true' if the user agent is a mobile user-agent.

Answer (score 2):

1. To create any plugin, you need to put this code into `di.xml` file :

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<config>
    <type name="{ObservedType}">
        <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{PluginClassName}" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Where :

**type name.** A class or interface which the plugin observes.

**plugin name.** An arbitrary plugin name that identifies a plugin. Also used to merge the configurations for the plugin.

**plugin type.** The name of a plugin’s class or its virtual type. Use the following naming convention when you specify this element: \Vendor\Extension\Plugin<ClassName>.

2. Then you need to create `plugin type` file like this one:

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin;

   class Yourpluginclassname
   {
       public function afterGetData($subject, $result)
       {
           return '|' . $result . '|';
       }
   }
   ```

For More information you can read here :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: can I order such a plugin from you?

Comment: Someone, who can help me a little more, how to build a module like this? Please :-)

Comment: Kindly check the devdoc link, which give you more and clear idea.